# SQL Hierarchy Fill Down

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an entity table that list row per entity, the rows are ordered (using id column) to show an implied hierarchy. **Note** for row 'B2', 'C1' does not get filled down because that is different second level entity.  The same with 'A3' last row.

I need to transform, Table_Entity (see sql definition below):

|  | id | Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 | Level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A1 | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2 | null | B1 | null | null |
| 2 | 3 | null | null | C1 | null |
| 3 | 4 | null | B2 | null | null |
| 4 | 5 | A2 | null | null | null |
| 5 | 6 | null | B3 | null | null |
| 6 | 7 | null | null | C2 | null |
| 7 | 8 | null | null | C3 | null |
| 8 | 9 | null | null | null | D1 |
| 9 | 10 | A3 | null | null | null |

to, Table_Entity_OUTPUT (see SQL definition below):

|  | id | Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 | Level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A1 | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2 | A1 | B1 | null | null |
| 2 | 3 | A1 | B1 | C1 | null |
| 3 | 4 | A1 | B2 | null | null |
| 4 | 5 | A2 | null | null | null |
| 5 | 6 | A2 | B3 | null | null |
| 6 | 7 | A2 | B3 | C2 | null |
| 7 | 8 | A2 | B3 | C3 | null |
| 8 | 9 | A2 | B3 | C3 | D1 |
| 9 | 10 | A3 | null | null | null |

SQL code for input and expected output tables

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Entity (
  id int,
  Level_1 Varchar(10),
  Level_2 Varchar(10),
  Level_3 Varchar(10),
  Level_4 Varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (1,'A1', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id,Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (2, null, 'B1', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (3, null, null, 'C1', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (4, null, 'B2', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (5, 'A2', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (6, null, 'B3', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (7, null, null, 'C2', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (8, null, null, 'C3', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (9, null, null, null, 'D1');
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (10, 'A3', null, null, null);

CREATE TABLE Table_Entity_OUTPUT (
  id int, 
  Level_1 Varchar(10),
  Level_2 Varchar(10),
  Level_3 Varchar(10),
  Level_4 Varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (1, 'A1', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (2, 'A1', 'B1', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (3, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (4, 'A1', 'B2', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (5, 'A2', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (6, 'A2', 'B3', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (7, 'A2', 'B3', 'C2', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (8, 'A2', 'B3', 'C3', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (9, 'A2', 'B3', 'C3', 'D1');
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (10, 'A3', null, null, null);
```

Comment: What is your question here? You've tagged [[tag:ansi-sql]], so does this mean that any solution cannot use any T-SQL only features?

Comment: I was hoping to generate a in-line sql query not using some sort of procedure.

Comment: What, in your sample data, links the value `B1` and `B2` to `A1`? Why not `A2` or `A3`? There is no relationship defined.

Comment: There is implied hierarchy based on the order of the fows.  "B1" and "B2" come under "A1".  "A2" is a different level one with its own child "B3".

Comment: There is no order to your rows; data in a table is unordered. Your table doesn't even have a clustered index, so it's a (aptly named) heap. Unless you have a way to relate your data, then you cannot achieve your desired results. You need to fix the problem at the root, as part of the `INSERT`, by the time it's in your table, it's too late.

Comment: @ThomA Yes, there needs to be an order column assigned.

Comment: @ScottBoston An order column can't be "assigned". SQL tables, data sets, etc, are by *definition* unordered. So, while you can infer an ordering from the order you wrote the data, that ordering doesn't actually exist in the data. Thus, ***you*** need to provide column/columns over which the data can be sorted and the missing values then be backfilled.

Comment: And please don't use images for data, use table markdown

Comment: @DaleK Updated to remove Ansi-sql

Comment: @MatBailie Added id to assign row order

Comment: Have you looked into using a _common table expression_ (CTE)? Since you have no explicit relationships between levels it would need to march through the rows in `id` order and propagate the various `Level_*` down. Other approaches using subexpressions and `top 1` or _window functions_ to look back through the table in descending `id` order ought to work.

Comment: Why have you chosen to use the string `'nan'` rather than use `null` to indicate _missing_ values? Surely it doesn't mean not-a-number since the other values aren't numbers. Or are they all hexadecimal?

Comment: @HABO My mistake from building markdown from python code.  Corrected.

Comment: Seems like you could just use `LAST_VALUE` and `IGNORE NULLS` here. What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work

Comment: @ThomA in python using the pandas library.  Logically, what I did was I filled each row to the right.  Next, I would fill down the null values with the last value in the column.  Lastly, I would remove duplicates to the right.

Comment: @ScottBoston - Thom A's answer is the best solution, but you need to use this as a reason for upgrading your SQL Server version from the now unsupported SQL Server 2012 to the latest. The `IGNORE NULLS` option is only available in SQL Server 2022 (and later). See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yTMXElaG).

Comment: @ThomA except that the stated version of SQL Server doesn't have IGNORE NULLS

Comment: @ThomA Thank you very much for the 2022 SQl Versino Ignore Nulls is quite powerful here.  Actually, I am will need to run this in "Dremio"  But all these solutions are helping.

Comment: @TN Further simplified... https://dbfiddle.uk/JjOvpNv9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absense of SKIP NULLS / IGNORE NULLS, my first thought is to create groups based on incremental changes in the relevant column AND its parent columns. Then use `MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)`.

```
WITH
  ids AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(Level_1) OVER (ORDER BY id)   AS Level_1_id,
    COUNT(Level_2) OVER (ORDER BY id)   AS Level_2_id,
    COUNT(Level_3) OVER (ORDER BY id)   AS Level_3_id,
    COUNT(Level_4) OVER (ORDER BY id)   AS Level_4_id
  FROM
    Table_Entity
)
SELECT
  *,
  MAX(Level_1) OVER (PARTITION BY Level_1_id),
  MAX(Level_2) OVER (PARTITION BY Level_1_id, Level_2_id),
  MAX(Level_3) OVER (PARTITION BY Level_1_id, Level_2_id, Level_3_id),
  MAX(Level_4) OVER (PARTITION BY Level_1_id, Level_2_id, Level_3_id, Level_4_id)
FROM
  ids
```

| id | Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 | Level_4 | Level_1_id | Level_2_id | Level_3_id | Level_4_id | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | A1 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | *null* | B1 | *null* | *null* | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | A1 | B1 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | *null* | *null* | C1 | *null* | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | A1 | B1 | C1 | *null* |
| 4 | *null* | B2 | *null* | *null* | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | A1 | B2 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | A2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | A2 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | *null* | B3 | *null* | *null* | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | A2 | B3 | *null* | *null* |
| 7 | *null* | *null* | C2 | *null* | 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 | A2 | B3 | C2 | *null* |
| 8 | *null* | *null* | C3 | *null* | 2 | 3 | 3 | 0 | A2 | B3 | C3 | *null* |
| 9 | *null* | *null* | *null* | D1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | A2 | B3 | C3 | D1 |
| 10 | A3 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | A3 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/USbgnh2s)

Answer (score 1):

It feels like there is something clever to be done with pivot or cross apply, but here's a sledgehammer approach.

**Rationale:**

First thing is to group the hierarchies. You can do this by deriving a hierarchy start indictor, then the cumulative sum of that gives you a sort of hierarchy id.

Then you define a level for the record, because as inferred from sample records 3&4 we only want to push down, never up.

Then a sequence of inline correlated subqueries to get the imputed value for the hierarchy group, capped at the record level. You could do this with an appropriated ranged window function as well.

**warning** - The max() here implicit assumes you'll have some ordering where the maximum is a sensible thing, as indicated by your sample data. If this is not the case it'd be pretty simple to tweak to make it explicit.

https://dbfiddle.uk/rdoM02oI

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Entity (
  id int,
  Level_1 Varchar(10),
  Level_2 Varchar(10),
  Level_3 Varchar(10),
  Level_4 Varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (1,'A1', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id,Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (2, null, 'B1', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (3, null, null, 'C1', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (4, null, 'B2', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (5, 'A2', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (6, null, 'B3', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (7, null, null, 'C2', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (8, null, null, 'C3', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (9, null, null, null, 'D1');
INSERT INTO Table_Entity(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (10, 'A3', null, null, null);

CREATE TABLE Table_Entity_OUTPUT (
  id int, 
  Level_1 Varchar(10),
  Level_2 Varchar(10),
  Level_3 Varchar(10),
  Level_4 Varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (1, 'A1', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (2, 'A1', 'B1', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (3, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (4, 'A1', 'B2', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (5, 'A2', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (6, 'A2', 'B3', null, null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (7, 'A2', 'B3', 'C2', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (8, 'A2', 'B3', 'C3', null);
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (9, 'A2', 'B3', 'C3', 'D1');
INSERT INTO Table_Entity_OUTPUT(id, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES (10, 'A3', null, null, null);

with group_hierarchies as
  (
    select
    id,
    level_1,
    level_2,
    level_3,
    level_4,
    case when level_4 is not null then 4
         when level_3 is not null then 3
         when level_2 is not null then 2
         else 1
     end as record_level,
    sum(start_new_hierarchy) over ( 
       order by id
       rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as h_group
    from (
    select case when level_1 is not null 
                 and coalesce(level_2,level_3,level_4) is null then 1
                else 0 
            end as start_new_hierarchy,
           * 
      from Table_Entity
    ) dummy_alias
  )
select id,
       (
         select level_1
           from group_hierarchies t2
          where t1.h_group = t2.h_group
            and t2.record_level = 1
       ) as level_1_impute,
       case when t1.record_level >= 2 then
       (
         select max(level_2)
           from group_hierarchies t2
          where t1.h_group = t2.h_group
            and t2.record_level = 2
            and t1.id >= t2.id
          group
             by t2.h_group
       ) end as level_2_impute,
       case when t1.record_level >= 3 then
       (
         select max(level_3)
           from group_hierarchies t2
          where t1.h_group = t2.h_group
            and t2.record_level = 3
            and t1.id >= t2.id
          group
             by t2.h_group
       ) end as level_3_impute,
       case when t1.record_level >= 4 then
       (
         select max(level_4)
           from group_hierarchies t2
          where t1.h_group = t2.h_group
            and t2.record_level = 4
            and t1.id >= t2.id
          group
             by t2.h_group
       ) end as level_4_impute
  from group_hierarchies t1;
```

| id | level_1_impute | level_2_impute | level_3_impute | level_4_impute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | A1 | B1 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | A1 | B1 | C1 | *null* |
| 4 | A1 | B2 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | A2 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | A2 | B3 | *null* | *null* |
| 7 | A2 | B3 | C2 | *null* |
| 8 | A2 | B3 | C3 | *null* |
| 9 | A2 | B3 | C3 | D1 |
| 10 | A3 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

Comment: Brute force? Or BRUTAL force? ;)

Comment: @MatBailie tour de force!

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `last_value ... ignore nulls` an elegant solution, but available only from version 2022.

The idea of the solution is `sort only by Id` (or use index on Id).

Tested for SQL Server from 2014 to 2022.

```
with t1 as(
select *
  ,max(case when Level_1 is null then 0 else rn end)over(order by id) L1_p
  ,max(case when Level_2 is null then 0 else rn end)over(order by id) L2_p
  ,max(case when Level_3 is null then 0 else rn end)over(order by id) L3_p
  ,max(case when Level_4 is null then 0 else rn end)over(order by id) L4_p
from  ( select *,row_number()over(order by id) rn   from Table_Entity )t0
)
,t2 as(
select *
  ,L1_p L1_px
  ,case when L2_p<L1_p then L1_p 
   else L2_p 
   end L2_px
  ,case when L3_p<L2_p then L2_p 
        when L3_p<L1_p then L1_p 
   else L3_p end L3_px
  ,case when L4_p<L3_p then L3_p 
        when L4_p<L2_p then L2_p 
        when L4_p<L1_p then L1_p
   else L4_p end L4_px
from t1
)
,t3 as (
select *
  ,lag(Level_1,rn-L1_px)over(order by id) L1_h
  ,lag(Level_2,rn-L2_px)over(order by id) L2_h
  ,lag(Level_3,rn-L3_px)over(order by id) L3_h
  ,lag(Level_4,rn-L4_px)over(order by id) L4_h
from t2
)
select * from t3;
```

| id | Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 | Level_4 | L1_h | L2_h | L3_h | L4_h | L1_px | L2_px | L3_px | L4_px | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | null | null | null | A1 | null | null | null | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | null | B1 | null | null | A1 | B1 | null | null | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | null | null | C1 | null | A1 | B1 | C1 | null | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | null | B2 | null | null | A1 | B2 | null | null | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | A2 | null | null | null | A2 | null | null | null | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | null | B3 | null | null | A2 | B3 | null | null | 5 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | null | null | C2 | null | A2 | B3 | C2 | null | 5 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 7 |
| 8 | null | null | C3 | null | A2 | B3 | C3 | null | 5 | 6 | 8 | 5 | 8 |
| 9 | null | null | null | D1 | A2 | B3 | C3 | D1 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 9 |
| 10 | A3 | null | null | null | A3 | null | null | null | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7vvWwsLq)

Comment: Yes. However, the plus here is that it works on SQL Server 2014 and quite possibly SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It turned out to be a good squeeze :)

Comment: Can you post it as an another answer?

Comment: As requested, optimised version of your answer added (and my comments here removed to keep things tidy)

Answer (score 0):

@valnik answer, with optimisations...

```
WITH
  t0 AS
(
  SELECT
    *
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)            AS rn
   ,CASE WHEN Level_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         WHEN Level_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 2
         WHEN Level_3 IS NOT NULL THEN 3
         WHEN Level_4 IS NOT NULL THEN 4 END   AS level_id
  FROM
    Table_Entity
),
  t1 AS
(
  SELECT
    *
   ,MAX(l1_row) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS L1_p
   ,MAX(l2_row) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS L2_p
   ,MAX(l3_row) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS L3_p
  from
    t0
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN level_id <= 1 THEN rn ELSE 0 END
     ,CASE WHEN level_id <= 2 THEN rn ELSE 0 END
     ,CASE WHEN level_id <= 3 THEN rn ELSE 0 END
  )
    AS source(l1_row, l2_row, l3_row)
)
SELECT
   *
  ,LAG(Level_1,rn-L1_p) OVER (ORDER BY id) L1_h
  ,LAG(Level_2,rn-L2_p) OVER (ORDER BY id) L2_h
  ,LAG(Level_3,rn-L3_p) OVER (ORDER BY id) L3_h 
  ,Level_4
FROM
  t1
ORDER BY
  id
```

| id | Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 | Level_4 | rn | level_id | l1_row | l2_row | l3_row | L1_p | L2_p | L3_p | L1_h | L2_h | L3_h | Level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | A1 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | *null* | B1 | *null* | *null* | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | A1 | B1 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | *null* | *null* | C1 | *null* | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | A1 | B1 | C1 | *null* |
| 4 | *null* | B2 | *null* | *null* | 4 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | A1 | B2 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | A2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 5 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | A2 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | *null* | B3 | *null* | *null* | 6 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 | A2 | B3 | *null* | *null* |
| 7 | *null* | *null* | C2 | *null* | 7 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 5 | 6 | 7 | A2 | B3 | C2 | *null* |
| 8 | *null* | *null* | C3 | *null* | 8 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 5 | 6 | 8 | A2 | B3 | C3 | *null* |
| 9 | *null* | *null* | *null* | D1 | 9 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 8 | A2 | B3 | C3 | D1 |
| 10 | A3 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 10 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | A3 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dXi4gi7Z)